# iCloud for all users of my app?

Tags: nsuserdefaults, icloud, multi-user

My first app is waiting approval in the store, wish me luck.  My question:

I bundle in a collection of presets, logos and URLs, several dozen, to make adding new entries easy.  I want to be able to rev this list of presets for all installed users without having to release a new app version to do it.  Right now the presets are part of the bundle but it would be the work of minutes to make them into a KV store like NSUserDefaults.  I could send this latest list to iCloud and all users of my app could sync to the latest list of presets.

But I've researched and I find nothing about doing this.  Revving the app is a very large hammer for a collection of presets and I would like to be able to update the list regularly.

Is there a way to do this?  Thanks for all the help I've gotten here.

Comment: IIRC you could load your presets (as long as they NOT code) from anywhere (for example via https from your server).

Comment: Certainly I could FTP them from elsewhere but that would be either a user-initiated pull or a lot of work to set up with notifications.  With iCloud I would have all that infrastructure already set up.  But yeah, a simple server based FTP is a good fallback.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

iCloud is a store on your entitlement but its not a shared resource each user will have your app id  in there iCould storage but  you can not push data to each user over iCloud you wont have access to iCloud storage of your users. you can store data in you users documents folder in your app sandbox and you could use push notification to tell your app to download more content Im not too sure and what you can add the the main bundle after the is shipped